# C#: How to register a type at application startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC Web application with several additional dlls. I'm trying to write some code that has a class in a dll implement an interface and register itself as an implementer of the interface. Why do I want to do this? Because I'd like the main application to be as generic as possible. I was thinking about something like a static constructor that would run at startup, but that's not when they run in c#. For example:

In a DLL.

```
public class DoIt : ICanDoThis
{
   //How can I register this class with the main application?
}
```

In the main Web application

```
public class Registrar
{
    public static void RegisterYourClass(string key, Type className)
    {
        //put incoming class into a dictionary by the key.
    }
    public static ICanDoThis GetWhoCanDoIt(string key)
    {
        //Get the class from the dictionary.
    }
}
```

Comment: http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/10/15/asp-net-5-mvc6-dependency-injection-in-6-steps/

Comment: This sounds like you're looking for a dependency injection library. Take a look at CastleWindsor or Spring.NET

Comment: **unclear what you're asking**. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Other than the built-in MVC DI Framework, I'd recommend SimpleInjector or Ninject. You need to do some research on IoC Containers (that's what they're called) and pick the one that best fits your needs.

Comment: `SimpleInjector` is very pleasant but its opinions may get in your way so definitely thoroughly research your options as @Novaterata suggests. Pretty much any popular DI library will support automatic registration.

Comment: +1 for Windsor, although the "big" ones (Windsor, Autofac, Unity) all work pretty much the same. A lot depends on which one you can find the easiest setup tutorial for.  [Here](https://gist.github.com/martinnormark/3128275) are some docs for Windsor. Once you learn this and do it you'll never go back. And then ASP.NET Core has it built in.